# D3 Data Loading For A Choropleth Graph or Heat Map

Tags: csv, d3.js

I am trying to use [this](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/a74faf20b492ad377312) as an example of US Choropleth graph (AKA Heat Map) for my own csv data. I copied the original code, and only changed the data source, then it is not working. So I figure that my data loading is wrong. But I can not figure out how to fix it. Could you help? Any help is appreciated.

Please see my code below or use this [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/qAHC2/1531/). Well, I don't know how to load my csv data in JSFiddle, so it is not supposed to work there anyway. I will share my csv file below.

Edit: One leeway I can think of is to add the data in JavaScript, which is not efficient, but works. I look into the original data format, and mimic it. I attach this "solution" at the bottom shown as Code 2.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    .state{
        fill: none;
        stroke: #a9a9a9;
        stroke-width: 1;
    }
    .state:hover{
        fill-opacity:0.5;
    }
    #tooltip {   
        position: absolute;           
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;             
        margin: 10px;
        font: 12px sans-serif;        
        background: lightsteelblue;   
        border: 1px;      
        border-radius: 2px;           
        pointer-events: none;         
    }
    #tooltip h4{
        margin:0;
        font-size:14px;
    }
    #tooltip{
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
        border:1px solid grey;
        border-radius:5px;
        font-size:12px;
        width:auto;
        padding:4px;
        color:white;
        opacity:0;
    }
    #tooltip table{
        table-layout:fixed;
    }
    #tooltip tr td{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    #tooltip tr td:nth-child(1){
        width:50px;
    }
    #tooltip tr td:nth-child(2){
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div id="tooltip"></div> <!-- div to hold tooltip. -->
<svg width="960" height="600" id="statesvg"></svg> <!-- svg to hold the map. -->
<script src="http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/raw/a74faf20b492ad377312/uStates.js"></script>  <!-- creates uStates. -->
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function tooltipHtml(n, d){ /* function to create html content string in tooltip div. */
        return "<h4>"+n+"</h4><table>"+
            "<tr><td>Net</td><td>"+(d.Net)+"</td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td>In</td><td>"+(d.In)+"</td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td>Out</td><td>"+(d.Out)+"</td></tr>"+
            "</table>";
    }

    var sampleData ={}; /* Sample random data. */   
    <!-- ["HI", "AK", "FL", "SC", "GA", "AL", "NC", "TN", "RI", "CT", "MA", "ME", "NH", "VT", "NY", "NJ", "PA", "DE", "MD",  -->
    <!-- "WV", "KY", "OH", "MI", "WY", "MT", "ID", "WA", "DC", "TX", "CA", "AZ", "NV", "UT", "CO", "NM", "OR", "ND", "SD",  -->
    <!-- "NE", "IA", "MS", "IN", "IL", "MN", "WI", "MO", "AR", "OK", "KS", "LS", "VA"] -->
    <!-- .forEach(function(d){  -->
            <!-- var Net=Math.round(100*Math.random()),  -->
            <!-- In=Math.round(100*Math.random()),  -->
            <!-- Out=Math.round(100*Math.random()); -->
    <!-- sampleData[d]={ -->
            <!-- Net:d3.min([Net,In,Out]),  -->
            <!-- In:d3.max([Net,In,Out]),  -->
            <!-- Out:Math.round((Net+In+Out)/3),  -->
            <!-- color:d3.interpolate("#ffffcc", "#800026")(Net/100)};  -->
        <!-- }); -->
    sampleData = d3.csv("Test.csv", function(data){
                         data.forEach(function(d) {
                         State: d.State,
                         Net: +d.Net,
                         In: +d.In,
                         Out: +d.Out,
                         color: d3.interpolate("#ffffcc", "#800026")(Net/100)};
                     });
        console.log(data[0]);
    });

    /* draw states on id #statesvg */   
    uStates.draw("#statesvg", sampleData, tooltipHtml);

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "600px"); 
</script>

</body>
```

CSV file:

```
State,Net,In,Out
"""AK""",12215,53952,41737
"""AL""",16443,35063,18620
"""AR""",62902,75160,12258
"""AZ""",13931,77911,63980
"""CA""",94043,98042,3999
"""CO""",59769,93780,34011
"""CT""",-14958,24957,39915
"""DC""",29903,86390,56487
"""DE""",-65779,16257,82036
"""FL""",-51446,34313,85759
"""GA""",29685,37768,8083
"""IA""",-42416,56750,99166
"""ID""",-32028,41536,73564
"""IL""",-86579,8818,95397
"""IN""",-38841,9576,48417
"""KS""",-20601,36955,57556
"""KY""",-1593,37728,39321
"""LS""",-2574,34066,36640
"""MA""",-47842,34838,82680
"""MD""",-46721,9290,56011
"""ME""",-65431,21563,86994
"""MI""",-6542,53094,59636
"""MN""",-6034,76869,82903
"""MO""",-73558,20641,94199
"""MS""",24958,87012,62054
"""MT""",28657,75139,46482
"""NC""",56536,79399,22863
"""ND""",27423,61184,33761
"""NE""",-32070,22564,54634
"""NH""",-60000,21133,81133
"""NJ""",-45478,45954,91432
"""NM""",54333,78167,23834
"""NV""",26792,55773,28981
"""NY""",-18735,35722,54457
"""OH""",-76722,10843,87565
"""OK""",23052,65474,42422
"""OR""",-31368,67948,99316
"""PA""",8303,70657,62354
"""RI""",4516,26086,21570
"""SC""",-57549,36354,93903
"""SD""",11788,46551,34763
"""TN""",38178,88302,50124
"""TX""",-8142,47607,55749
"""UT""",-59301,20661,79962
"""VA""",-44967,27957,72924
"""VT""",95214,98784,3570
"""WA""",32652,33543,891
"""WI""",10484,23835,13351
"""WV""",12462,31829,19367
"""WY""",-20751,49812,70563
"""HI""",-54981,7388,62369
```

Code 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    .state{
        fill: none;
        stroke: #a9a9a9;
        stroke-width: 1;
    }
    .state:hover{
        fill-opacity:0.5;
    }
    #tooltip {   
        position: absolute;           
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;             
        margin: 10px;
        font: 12px sans-serif;        
        background: lightsteelblue;   
        border: 1px;      
        border-radius: 2px;           
        pointer-events: none;         
    }
    #tooltip h4{
        margin:0;
        font-size:14px;
    }
    #tooltip{
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
        border:1px solid grey;
        border-radius:5px;
        font-size:12px;
        width:auto;
        padding:4px;
        color:white;
        opacity:0;
    }
    #tooltip table{
        table-layout:fixed;
    }
    #tooltip tr td{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    #tooltip tr td:nth-child(1){
        width:50px;
    }
    #tooltip tr td:nth-child(2){
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div id="tooltip"></div> <!-- div to hold tooltip. -->
<svg width="960" height="600" id="statesvg"></svg> <!-- svg to hold the map. -->
<script src="http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/raw/a74faf20b492ad377312/uStates.js"></script>  <!-- creates uStates. -->
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function tooltipHtml(n, d){ /* function to create html content string in tooltip div. */
        return "<h4>"+n+"</h4><table>"+
            "<tr><td>Net</td><td>"+(d.Net)+"</td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td>In</td><td>"+(d.In)+"</td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td>Out</td><td>"+(d.Out)+"</td></tr>"+
            "</table>";
    }

    var sampleData ={}; /* Sample random data. */   
    <!-- 1. Original Solution -->
    <!-- ["HI", "AK", "FL", "SC", "GA", "AL", "NC", "TN", "RI", "CT", "MA", "ME", "NH", "VT", "NY", "NJ", "PA", "DE", "MD",  -->
    <!-- "WV", "KY", "OH", "MI", "WY", "MT", "ID", "WA", "DC", "TX", "CA", "AZ", "NV", "UT", "CO", "NM", "OR", "ND", "SD",  -->
    <!-- "NE", "IA", "MS", "IN", "IL", "MN", "WI", "MO", "AR", "OK", "KS", "LS", "VA"] -->
    <!-- .forEach(function(d){  -->
            <!-- var Net=Math.round(100*Math.random()),  -->
            <!-- In=Math.round(100*Math.random()),  -->
            <!-- Out=Math.round(100*Math.random()); -->
    <!-- sampleData[d]={ -->
            <!-- Net:d3.min([Net,In,Out]),  -->
            <!-- In:d3.max([Net,In,Out]),  -->
            <!-- Out:Math.round((Net+In+Out)/3),  -->
            <!-- color:d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(Net/100)};  -->
        <!-- }); -->

    <!-- 2. Load CSV -->
    <!-- sampleData = d3.csv("Test.csv", function(data){ -->
                         <!-- data.forEach(function(d) { -->
                         <!-- d.Net = +d.Net; -->
                         <!-- d.In = +d.In; -->
                         <!-- d.Out = +d.Out; -->
                         <!-- color = d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(Net/100)}; -->
                     <!-- }); -->
        <!-- console.log(data[0]); -->
    <!-- }); -->

    <!-- 3. Load Data -->
    sampleData = {
"AK":{"Net":13673,"In":72772,"Out":59099,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.568365)},
"AL":{"Net":46349,"In":59672,"Out":13323,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.731745)},
"AR":{"Net":-31164,"In":38140,"Out":69304,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.34418)},
"AZ":{"Net":-27113,"In":57824,"Out":84937,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.364435)},
"CA":{"Net":-42460,"In":12772,"Out":55232,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.2877)},
"CO":{"Net":9039,"In":9163,"Out":124,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.545195)},
"CT":{"Net":-8192,"In":60579,"Out":68771,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.45904)},
"DC":{"Net":15000,"In":45262,"Out":30262,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.575)},
"DE":{"Net":39455,"In":93112,"Out":53657,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.697275)},
"FL":{"Net":6592,"In":44256,"Out":37664,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.53296)},
"GA":{"Net":19317,"In":25254,"Out":5937,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.596585)},
"IA":{"Net":119,"In":46902,"Out":46783,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.500595)},
"ID":{"Net":21304,"In":94961,"Out":73657,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.60652)},
"IL":{"Net":6726,"In":96451,"Out":89725,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.53363)},
"IN":{"Net":66445,"In":71900,"Out":5455,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.832225)},
"KS":{"Net":43263,"In":63770,"Out":20507,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.716315)},
"KY":{"Net":28409,"In":39524,"Out":11115,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.642045)},
"LS":{"Net":-32758,"In":36865,"Out":69623,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.33621)},
"MA":{"Net":-77135,"In":20768,"Out":97903,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.114325)},
"MD":{"Net":33582,"In":52556,"Out":18974,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.66791)},
"ME":{"Net":-33661,"In":63381,"Out":97042,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.331695)},
"MI":{"Net":25521,"In":46300,"Out":20779,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.627605)},
"MN":{"Net":-67244,"In":23014,"Out":90258,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.16378)},
"MO":{"Net":-31720,"In":28241,"Out":59961,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.3414)},
"MS":{"Net":45311,"In":61848,"Out":16537,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.726555)},
"MT":{"Net":-6116,"In":33017,"Out":39133,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.46942)},
"NC":{"Net":-1072,"In":32219,"Out":33291,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.49464)},
"ND":{"Net":30661,"In":42404,"Out":11743,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.653305)},
"NE":{"Net":68355,"In":99399,"Out":31044,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.841775)},
"NH":{"Net":18610,"In":61242,"Out":42632,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.59305)},
"NJ":{"Net":38709,"In":61706,"Out":22997,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.693545)},
"NM":{"Net":15182,"In":46812,"Out":31630,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.57591)},
"NV":{"Net":-10893,"In":86934,"Out":97827,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.445535)},
"NY":{"Net":-54467,"In":40371,"Out":94838,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.227665)},
"OH":{"Net":21695,"In":26311,"Out":4616,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.608475)},
"OK":{"Net":-50523,"In":30579,"Out":81102,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.247385)},
"OR":{"Net":-51906,"In":37801,"Out":89707,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.24047)},
"PA":{"Net":-89879,"In":2858,"Out":92737,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.050605)},
"RI":{"Net":-3146,"In":6730,"Out":9876,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.48427)},
"SC":{"Net":22085,"In":54977,"Out":32892,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.610425)},
"SD":{"Net":28055,"In":58411,"Out":30356,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.640275)},
"TN":{"Net":-75690,"In":4153,"Out":79843,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.12155)},
"TX":{"Net":-55786,"In":27575,"Out":83361,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.22107)},
"UT":{"Net":-63853,"In":76,"Out":63929,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.180735)},
"VA":{"Net":44965,"In":69720,"Out":24755,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.724825)},
"VT":{"Net":-18735,"In":39534,"Out":58269,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.406325)},
"WA":{"Net":-8462,"In":48597,"Out":57059,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.45769)},
"WI":{"Net":-53972,"In":28418,"Out":82390,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.23014)},
"WV":{"Net":-2571,"In":60715,"Out":63286,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.487145)},
"WY":{"Net":-16086,"In":52706,"Out":68792,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.41957)},
"HI":{"Net":1418,"In":15119,"Out":13701,"color":d3.interpolate("#ffff32", "#3232ff")(0.50709)}
};


    /* draw states on id #statesvg */   
    uStates.draw("#statesvg", sampleData, tooltipHtml);

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "600px"); 
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can use d3.json in the manner you are. I haven't seen it before at least. Also, your forEach code won't give you the result you are looking for. Your code as is should produce an error like this:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement[Learn More]  map.html:71:28
```

When you are coloring the paths you need to have a property that has the state abbreviation (which holds an object of properties such as color). You need to make a dictionary. You could use:

```
var sampleData ={};     
d3.csv("Test.csv", function(data){
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    sampleData[d.State] = { 
      Net : +d.Net, 
      In : +d.In, 
      Out : +d.Out, 
      color : d3.interpolate("#ffffcc", "#800026")(d.Net/100) 
    };
  });
});
```

Loggin `sampleData` will give you something like:

```
Object { AK: Object, AL: Object, AR: Object, AZ: Object, CA: Object, CO: Object, CT: Object, DC: Object, DE: Object, FL: Object, 41 more… }
```

But, `sampleData` will only be defined in the callback function of d3.json - as `d3.json` is asynchronous. Therefore you'll need to call the drawing function within it.

So your code should look like:

```
var sampleData ={};     
d3.csv("Test.csv", function(data){
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    sampleData[d.State] = { 
      Net : +d.Net, 
      In : +d.In, 
      Out : +d.Out, 
      color : d3.interpolate("#ffffcc", "#800026")(d.Net/100) 
    };
  });
  uStates.draw("#statesvg", sampleData, tooltipHtml);
});
```

This gives me this:

[image]

The data is pairing properly (you can see the values in the mouseover). However, while not in your question, your colors are not done properly, they are all `#ffffff` or `#000000`. Try using a scale:

```
var sampleData ={};     
d3.csv("Test.csv", function(data){
  var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .range(["steelblue","orange"])
    .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.Net/100; }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Net/100; }) ])
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    sampleData[d.State] = { 
      Net : +d.Net, 
      In : +d.In, 
      Out : +d.Out, 
      color : color(d.Net/100);
    };
  });
});
```

Which gives me:

[image]

[Here is a demonstration](http://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/3548acc6877d304e3a5a3e623de22678) of your code in action with the above tweaks. Oh, and I also removed the quotations from the csv file, no need to include them.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much, @Andrew Reid